# Is there any way to add MULTIPLE classes to body tag in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add multiple classes to body tag in magento using addbodyclass method in my local.xml file.

Code in my local.xml file

```
<reference name="root">
     <action method="addBodyClass">
        <className helper="mymodule/addbodyclass/addClasses" />
     </action>
</reference>
```

Code in my Helper class in a custom module:

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Helper_Addbodyclass extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function addClasses() {
        return "classname1 classname2 classname3";
     }
}
```

This adds classes in one string like this:

> classname1-classname2-classname3

in the body tag.

Instead of spaces it adds dash(-). I know this is default behavior of magento. **But is there a way to actually add spaces and not dash(-)**.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the `addBodyClass` method replaces some characters with `-` on the fly using regular expression:

```
public function addBodyClass($className)
{
    $className = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', strtolower($className));
    $this->setBodyClass($this->getBodyClass() . ' ' . $className);
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, when this method is called **the original body classes are updated and the extra body class is added with a space between the original classes**. So in order to add several classes I suggest you do the following in your xml file:

```
<action method="addBodyClass">
     <className>classname1</className>
</action>
<action method="addBodyClass">
     <className>classname2</className>
</action>
<action method="addBodyClass">
     <className>classname3</className>
</action>
```

If you really want to be able to add several classes to the body using that method, then you will need to create a custom module that extends that method:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>

    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_Multiplebodyclass>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </DigitalPianism_Multiplebodyclass>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <blocks>
              <page>
                   <rewrite>
                        <html>DigitalPianism_Multiplebodyclass_Block_Page_Html</html>
                   </rewrite>
              </page>
         </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

**Block/Page/Html.php**

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_Multiplebodyclass_Block_Page_Html extends Mage_Page_Block_Html
{
    public function addBodyClass($classNames)
    {
        if (is_array($classNames))
        {
            foreach($classNames as $className)
            {
                parent::addBodyClass($className);
            }
        }
        else parent::addBodyClass($classNames);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then in your custom helper you will be able to do:

```
public function addClasses() {
        return array('classname1','classname2','classname3');
     }
```

Comment: I know this way also about adding classes in xml file one by one. But this is a tedious job to maintain specially when you have classnames generated dynamically. So i chose to go with helper method addClasses.

Comment: @JayBabani see my edited answer for further possibilities

Comment: Perfect Solution. I think magento team guys should add this code in their core files. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, you cannot do that because the `addBodyClass` looks like this:

```
public function addBodyClass($className)
{
    $className = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', strtolower($className));
    $this->setBodyClass($this->getBodyClass() . ' ' . $className);
    return $this;
}
```

It replaces anything that's not alphanumeric with `-`.

The solutions I see are (in the order of easiness to implement):

1. You add a tag `<action method="addBodyClass">` to the layout for each class you need. This may not always work if you want to add a variable number of classes.
2. rewrite the method `Mage_Page_Block_Html::addBodyClass` to allow you to use spaces in the class names.
3. Create an other block that does notout put html but calls `addBodyClass` method as many times as you need.
   Something like this.

   ```
   <reference name="root">
        <block type="[module]/some_name">
            <action method="addRequiredBodyClasses" />
        </block>
   </reference>
   ```

   then create the block `[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Some_Name`.

   ```
   <?php 
   class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Some_Name extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
   {
       protected function _toHtml()
       {
           return '';
       }
       public function addRequiredBodyClasses()
       {
           $bodyClasses = Mage::helper('mymodule/addbodyclass')->addClasses();
           $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();//this will get you the root block;
           if ($parentBlock instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html)
           {
                $bodyClassesArray = explode(' ', $bodyClasses);
                foreach ($bodyClassesArray as $class) {
                    $parentBlock->addBodyClass($class);
                }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: this looks interesting. I will try this. Thank you so much